# checking if certain characters are in a string in C

Tags: c, string, character

Hi I'm a newbie C learner and this is an assignment.

The task is to write a program that changes a user's password and check if the new given password includes at least a number, a letter and one of these (`@`, `#`, `$`, `%`) signs and its length should be between 6 and 20.

I've described 3 variables as `counter1`, `counter2` & `counter3` to check if at least a sign, a number & a letter is in the given password and if one of them was 0 scan another password from the user. This should continue until an entered password includes all the terms above.

My program will check the numbers, letters & the signs in given password but as the first new password is entered the program will end whether it contains all the terms or not, this is the part of the program that I assume the problem is from

```
int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0, counter3 = 0;
char mypassword[20] = "A1$B2C";
char password[20];
char newpassword[50];
int check = 0;
do {
    printf("Please enter your current password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);
} while (strcmp(mypassword, password) != 0);
printf("Please enter your new password: ");
scanf("%s", newpassword);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(newpassword); i++) {
    if (isalpha(newpassword[i]) != 0) {
        counter3 += 1;
    }
    else if (isdigit(newpassword[i]) != 0) {
        counter2 += 1;
    }
    else if (newpassword[i] == '@' || '#' || '$' || '%') {
        counter1 += 1;
    }
}
while (check == 0) {
    while (counter1 == 0 || counter2 == 0 || counter3 == 0) {
        printf("Please enter you new password: ");
        scanf("%s", newpassword);
    }
    if (strlen(newpassword) < 6 || strlen(newpassword) > 20) {
        printf("Please enter you new password: ");
        scanf("%s", newpassword);
    }
    else
        check += 1;
}
```

Comment: You must update `counter1`, `counter2`, and `counter3` according to the new password.

Comment: You really, really should use more descriptive variable names,

Comment: @JCWasmx86 Indeed.  `counter3` should be something like `alphaCount`, `counter2` something like `digitCount`, and `counter1` something like `symbolCount`.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other problems, it does not contain a `main()` function. In fact, it does not contain ANY function. It is missing the needed `#include` statements.

Comment: OT:  regarding statements like: `scanf("%s", newpassword);`  1) when using the `%s` and/or `%[...]` input format specifiers, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because these specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids any buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.   2) Always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of matching specifiers.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0, counter3 = 0;`  1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) a variable name should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)

Comment: OT: given this critieria: *and its length should be between 6 and 20.* why is the array: `newpassword[]` declared as 50 characters?   Since the password is a char array, and a char string always must have a NUL byte at the end, and the password can be up to 20 characters long: why is the array: `password[]` only declared as 20 characters rather than 21 characters.

Comment: OT: for a good application, before the code inputs the newpassword, the code should inform the user of the criteria for that password

Comment: OT: regarding: `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(newpassword); i++) {`  1) the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not a `int`.  2) this will result in the function: `strlen()` being called over and over and over.   Better to save the returned value in a variable: `size_t length = strlen( newpassword );`  Then reference that saved value in the `for()` statement:  `for ( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {`

Comment: OT: regarding: `else if (newpassword[i] == '@' || '#' || '$' || '%') {`   Since the `newpassword` is from characters from the keyboard of the user, why limit to only 4 characters.  BTW:  that statement will not work.  Each value must be compared.  Suggest: `else if (newpassword[i] == '@' || newpassword[i] == '#' || newpassword[i] == '$' || newpassword[i] == '%') {`

Answer (score 2):

The test for special characters is incorrect: `if (newpassword[i] == '@' || '#' || '$' || '%')` will always succeed because `'#'` taken as a boolean is true.

You should instead write:

```
int c = newpassword[i];
if (c == '@' || c == '#' || c == '$' || c == '%') {
    counter1++;
}
```

There are other problems in your code:

- you do not pass a maximum number of characters for `scanf()` to read into `password`: any input word longer than 19 bytes will cause undefined behavior.
- you do not test for `scanf()` failure: unexpected end of file will cause undefined behavior and likely an endless loop.
- you should be more explicit about the reason for prompting for the new password again.
- the counters should be reset to `0` for each new password entered and their names should be more meaningful.
- all tests must be tried again for every new attempt: Use a `for` loop with a single instance of `scanf()` to read the current or new password, perform the tests and exit the loop if all tests succeed. As a rule of thumb, avoid `do`/`while` loops as they tend to induce confusing and redundant code.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int get_new_password(char *output,              // destination array, longer than max_length
                     int min_length,            // minimum password length
                     int max_length,            // maximum password length
                     const char *special_chars, // set of special chars if any required
                     const char *current_pwd)   // current password if any
{
    char password[50];
    char newpassword[50];
    int has_letter, has_digit, has_special, len, c;

    if (current_pwd != NULL && *current_pwd != '\0') {
        for (;;) {
            printf("Please enter your current password: ");
            if (scanf("%49s", password) != 1)
                return -1;
            if (strcmp(current_pwd, password) != 0) {
                printf("Invalid password. Try again.\n");
                continue;
            }
            break;  // current password is correct.
        }
    }

    for (;;) {
        printf("Please enter your new password: ");
        if (scanf("%49s", newpassword) != 1)
            return -1;

        len = strlen(newpassword);
        if (len < min_length) {
            printf("The password must have at least %d characters.\n", min_length);
            continue;
        }
        if (len > max_length) {
            printf("The password must have at most %d characters.\n", max_length);
            continue;
        }
        has_letter = has_digit = has_special = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            c = newpassword[i];
            if (isalpha((unsigned char)c)) {
                has_letter = 1;
            } else
            if (isdigit((unsigned char)c)) {
                has_digit = 1;
            } else
            if (special_chars && strchr(special_chars, c) != NULL) {
                has_special = 1;
            }
        }
        if (has_letter == 0) {
            printf("The password must have at least one letter.\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (has_digit == 0) {
            printf("The password must have at least one digit.\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (special_chars != NULL && has_special == 0) {
            printf("The password must have at least one of %s\n", special_chars);
            continue;
        }
        break;  // new password passed all tests
    }
    strcpy(output, newpassword);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char mypassword[] = "A1$B2C";
    char newpassword[21];

    if (get_new_password(newpassword, 6, 20, "@#$%", mypassword)) {
        printf("Invalid input, aborted.\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("New password: %s\n", newpassword);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you would break your validation into a separate function, makes the code more readable. Below is a suggestion, which also lets you easily print out which validation criteria fails in case of an invalid password.

```
#define VALIDATE_OK 0
#define VALIDATE_TOO_SHORT (1 << 0)
#define VALIDATE_TOO_LONG (1 << 1)
#define VALIDATE_LETTER (1 << 2)
#define VALIDATE_DIGIT (1 << 3)
#define VALIDATE_SPECIAL_CHAR (1 << 4)

#define MIN_LENGTH 6
#define MAX_LENGTH 20

static int validate(const char *str) {
    const char special_chars[] = { '@', '#', '$', '%' };
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    int ret = VALIDATE_TOO_SHORT|VALIDATE_TOO_LONG|VALIDATE_LETTER|
        VALIDATE_DIGIT|VALIDATE_SPECIAL_CHAR;

    if (len >= MIN_LENGTH) ret &= ~VALIDATE_TOO_SHORT;
    if (len <= MAX_LENGTH) ret &= ~VALIDATE_TOO_LONG;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)str[i])) {
             ret &= ~VALIDATE_LETTER;
             continue;
        }
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)str[i])) {
            ret &= ~VALIDATE_DIGIT;
            continue;
        }
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof special_chars; j++) {
            if (str[i] == special_chars[j]) {
                ret &= ~VALIDATE_SPECIAL_CHAR;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

EDIT: Now properly returns all missing criteria.

Comment: Naked `char` values should not be passed to `isalpha()` or `isdigit()` because they ould be negative on platforms where `char` is signed by default, causing undefined behavior as the functions from `<ctype.h>` are only defined for `int` arguments with a value of `EOF` or that of an `unsigned char`. To avoid this problem, `char` values must be cast as `(unsigned char)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use strchr (https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/). If the char wasn't found, it returns a null pointer.

Edit:
Another solution would be to use a for loop:

```
size_t len=strlen(newpassword);
if(len<3||len>20){
  //Invalid length
}
int hasDigit=0;
int hasSpecial=0;
int hasLetter=0;
for(size_t i=0;i<len;i++) {
  char c=newpassword[i];
  if(isdigit(c)){
    hasDigit=1;
  }else if(c=='@'||c=='#'||c=='$'||c=='%'){
    hasSpecial=1;
  }else{
    hasLetter=1;
  }
  ...
}
if(hasDigit&&hasSpecial&&hasLetter){
  //Valid password
}
```

Edit 2:

```
if (isalpha(newpassword[i]) != 0){
        counter3 += 1;
    }
```

I think this shouldn't be there and simply in the else clause:

```
else{
   counter3 += 1;
}
```

(This will be too long for a comment)
Lets start at the beginning:

1. You ask the user for the current password.
   1.1 Repeat, if it's the wrong one.
2. You ask for the new one.
3. You go about every char in the new password. 
   3.1 If it is a digit, add 1 to counter 2 
   3.2 If it is a special char, add 1 to counter 1 
   3.3 Here you should simply add 1 to counter1. 
   4.After that you enter the `while(check == 0)`-Loop 
   4.1 You enter the `while(counter1 == 0 || counter2 == 0 || counter3 == 0)` loop, these will be endless, as it is impossible to changle one of the counter variables. 
   4.2 Everything else is dead code, because it can't be accessed.

Comment: i have used strchr() to find characters and the counters do work but the problem is when i enter a new password whether it contains at least a letter, a number and a sign or not the program ends

Comment: still has that same problem. the program breaks after i enter a new password once. i've edited my code, would be thankful if you would take a look

Comment: @Palreza (assuming this is the bulk of your program) the only checks your last loop performs are ones for length, not for any of the other criteria.

Comment: sorry the code was wrong i've edited it once again, and now it requests for a new password in an never ending loop even when i enter a password with all the terms it doesnt beak

Comment: Because the loop body never performs validation and/or updates the counter variables.

Comment: but if i enter a password with letters, numbers, and signs none of the counters would be 0 and shouldn't the loop breaks?